# Keeping multiple controllers in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it good practice to have multiple controllers in scope so that you can go back and forth between binding to each throughout a document?

For instance, if I want to interleave the values of two sets of price/quantity/total, is it bad design to do the following: [On Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dca3I10hsW4PLBI8wDoW?p=preview)

```
<html ng-app="invoiceTest">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="invoiceTest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice1">
  <span ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice2">

   <div>Cost 1: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice1.cost" required ></div>
   <div>Cost 2: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice2.cost" required ></div>

   <div>Quantity 1: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice1.qty" required ></div>
   <div> Quantity 2: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice2.qty" required ></div>

   <div><b>Total 1: </b>{{invoice1.total('USD') | currency}}</div>
   <div><b>Total 2: </b>{{invoice2.total('USD') | currency}}</div>

  </span>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Alternatively, is there a way to carry multiple controls in scope without nesting them, or point the scope of an element to a previously declared controller instance?

Thanks for any advice. I'm just getting started with angular. I'm used to (MVVM) frameworks where the element you're binding to is instantiated in the ViewModel, not in the View itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to say that your use case is a little contrived.  Your example really only needs one controller that had an array of objects, each one having a quantity and price.

I would say that I can't think of a situation where two controllers would be a good idea; controllers are supposed to be pretty independent, and if you have two controllers over the same code, you open yourself up to collisions and trouble.  That's not to say that you shouldn't nest logic -- putting logic in directives can be a great idea, and that's kind of a controller inside a controller -- but using two controllers together usually implies that you want to share data between them, which can get clumsy fast.

Getting user to angular takes time, but in your example, I would try refactoring your controller to have an array of objects, then using directives like `ng-repeat` to generate your html for you, rather than writing it yourself.  Angular is very powerful at turning your model into a view, and once you use it enough I think you'll see that using multiple controllers isn't the worst idea, but there's almost always a better solution that's both easier to write and easier to maintain.

**EDIT:**

As an example, here's your original example under one controller, and a full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4HJh/14/) showing it working.

```
app.controller('OneController', function($scope){
  $scope.invoices = [
    { cost: 100,
     qty: 5,
     total: function(){return this.cost*this.qty}
    },//etc.
  ];
});

app.directive('compareInvoices', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        invoices: '='
    },
    template:'<div>'+
              '<div ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">Cost {{$index+1}}: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice.cost" required ></div>'+
              '<div ng-repeat="invoice in invoices">Quantity {{$index+1}}: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice.qty" required ></div>'+
              '<div ng-repeat="invoice in invoices"><b>Total {{$index+1}}: </b>{{invoice.total()}}</div>'+
              '</div>'
  }
});
```

It creates the same HTML you had originally, but could also handle any number of invoices instead of just 2, and if you wanted to compare the two invoices, you could easily do that inside your controller because it had immediate access to both.

Comment: A real use case is when someone is doing year on year comparisons. They can pick any two 'objects' which each have dozens of fields, and want to view their properties side by side. In that case I need to load them both up and interleave their data for easy comparison.